# ドメイン.redではLINEのタイムラインに対応していない？

Tags: line-opengraph, opengraph

LINEタイムラインに、ブログのサムネイルやタイトルを表示させたいのですが、うまく表示されません。
問題の起きているブログ、データベースを他のドメイン(.com/.co.jp)にインポートして表示させると、うまく表示されました。
もしかすると.redのドメインに問題があるのではないかと思いました。
新しいドメインなので対応されていないのかと思い質問させていただきました。
同じような問題に直面した方などおりましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINEで試したわけではありませんが、一般的に新gTLDへの対応は一筋縄ではいかない場合が多いです。

今どれだけ多くのTLDが登録されているかご存知ですか？
IANAは以下のリストを掲載していますが、ドメインは日々（ほんとに！）追加されています。
http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

.redドメインに問題があるというより、新gTLD対応の費用対効果が見込めないというのが本音じゃないかと思います。一度LINEのサポートに連絡されてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
やはり対応されていない可能性はありえるわけですね。
LINEのサポートには連絡しました。
電話でのお問い合わせがなかったので、メールでのお問い合わせですが、返事が返ってこない事もあるようなので気長に待ってみます。
ありがとうございました。